# OpenSSH windows 10 user's password not configured

Tags: windows-10, openssh

I'm currently using openSSH and my admin user configured without login password, i.e automatically logging in during startup. I wonder what happens in such case, is there an automatic default password for SSH connectivity?

I've another related question, during installation I chose "Run as LOCAL_SYSTEM" what does it mean?

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
```

Comment: Please don't post images with text. [Edit] the question and add the actual text instead. Its much easier to read, copy paste, and search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default OpenSSH does not allow empty passwords, as you can read in manual page for `sshd_config`.

> `PermitEmptyPasswords`
>
> When password authentication is allowed, it specifies whether the server allows login to accounts with empty password strings.  The default is `no`.

This is reasonable for remote login. Unless you change this option, or set a password for your user, you should not be able to use SSH to log in to your system.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using password, you may consider using Public Key. Leaving the passphrase blank when generating the key pair allows you to log in using public key without typing password.